# Apollo Server deployed on AWS Beanstalk Node.js cannot be reached if authorisation header is provided

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nginx-reverse-proxy, apollo-server

I have ApolloServer (without applying express middelware) deployed on AWS Beanstalk nodejs platform.

When I passed the authorisation header in a call, I get time-out response. For example:

- I query the server to return data of current user. When I omit the authorisation header, I get the correct response, i.e. the user is not authenticated.
- I query the same endpoint, but provide the authorisation in the header. I get 504 gateway time-out exception

## How to reproduce

- Configure Apollo Server to enable CORS
- Deploy basic Apollo Server on the AW EB nodejs
- Configure ALB to use https and listener for 443 port. Set is as default and disable listener for port 80.
- Call an authorised endpoint without the authorisation in the header.
- Call an authorised endpoint including the authorisation in the header.

## Tried so far

- Looking at logs in my application. I do not see logs that the endpoint is invoked if authorisation header is provided.
- Looking at ALB logs. I see that it forwards the request to Nginx and the response is 504.

My guess is that is its something on the Nginx side. I am looking at the Nginx logs, i.e. at files `access.log` and `error.log` in the `/var/log/nginx` directory, but I do not see any logs inside. So I am trying to find out how to enable those logs.

## Solution

I was on a wrong trail. After streaming my logs into AWS CloudWatch and seeing the logs live, I noticed that I can actually see the application logs and that I see the authorisation in the header. I do not have a clue why I was not able to see that before.

Anyway, after being able to track the application logs, I noticed that my request to ElastiCache Redis is timing-out which is actually the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was on a wrong trail. After streaming my logs into AWS CloudWatch and seeing the logs live, I noticed that I can actually see the application logs and that I see the authorisation in the header. I do not have a clue why I was not able to see that before.

Anyway, after being able to track the application logs, I noticed that my request to ElastiCache Redis is timing-out which is actually the cause of the issue